# No access to an Object in an Array, but to the object itself

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, for-loop

I have the following code, creating objects within a loop and then accessing values of them. Now I came to the problem, that accessing the object itself is ok, but not the array that contains the object. Am I missing something here?

```
camList = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    var camObj = new Camera(i);
    camList.push(camObj);
    console.log(camObj.id);     //this works
    console.log(camList[i].id); //this doesnt
}
```

PS: In this example camObj.id just returns the current value of i.

PPS: I got a TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

---

Edit:

I added a full code example.

Camera Object:

```
var Camera = function(id, cam)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.cam = cam;
    this.res =  {
                    "x" : this.cam.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
                    "y" : this.cam.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
                };
    this.overlayData = new Array();
};

exports.Camera = Camera;
```

Main Code:

```
var cv      = require("opencv-node");
var Camera  = require("./cameraModule").Camera;
var camList = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    var capture = new cv.VideoCapture();
    capture.open(i);

    if (capture.isOpened())
    {
        var camObj = new Camera(i, capture);
        camList.push(camObj);
        console.log(camList[i].id); //Here is the problem
    }
}
```

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: Where do you define `camList`?  Are you sure your `i` lines up with its index?  What do you see if you `console.log(camList);`?

Comment: Agree with @RocketHazmat -- Index's probably aren't aligning.

Comment: Yes, we need to see the earlier code that creates `var camList`. If you previously pushed onto it, the indices will have already advanced beyond your current zero-based values of `i`.

Comment: If you intend for the index to line up, perhaps you mean to `camList[i] = camObj;`

Comment: @SLaks: I got a TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: camList is defined above the loop as camList = new Array();

Comment: Post enough code to reproduce your problem. One should be able to take your example, run it, and get the same result you're experiencing. That's not the case with the code you provided.

Comment: Your updated question doesn't reproduce the issue you describe. Please don't post examples that you've not bothered to verify as being relevant to the issue.

Comment: You said "camObj.id just returns the current value of i".  Is that not supposed to happen?  You're passing `i` to `new Camera`, so what should the `id` be?  What *should* it return?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: OP is describing what `camObj.id` represents.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yes, camObj.id returns the expected value, but if I use camList[i].id instead I run into a Type Error.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Ah, yes.  I misread that, sorry.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Well, it's not like the question is terribly clear.

Comment: @Fidel90: Your code, as posted, works fine  http://jsfiddle.net/MPfUV/1/  Is there other code that modifies `camList`?  Can you make your own example that shows it not working?

Comment: @CrazyTrain: I'm running this on a RaspberryPi with node.js and OpenCV Bindings so I guess not much people will be able to just copy&paste my code to test it, so i reduced it to the minimum to keep an eye on the problem.

Comment: @Fidel90: What do you see if you `console.log(camList)` after the `camList.push` line?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: With the code i posted above adding the line you said I get "[ { id: 1, cam: {}, res: { x: 640, y: 480 }, overlayData: [] } ]" - curious, dont kn ow whats going wrong here...

Comment: @Fidel90: Here's a hint, what happens if `capture.isOpened()` is `false`?  Where would `i` be in relation to how many items are in `camList`?

Comment: @Fidel90: Well, when this condition fails... `if (capture.isOpened())` ...you're still incrementing `i`, so `i` will be ahead of the last index. Can you now see why it's important to post an actual working example of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In each loop iteration, you are checking `capture.isOpened()`.  What would happen if that was `false`?

The loop would continue *without* something being pushed into `camList`.  On the next loop, `i` would be incremented.  Let's say `capture.isOpened()` becomes `true`.  When you insert into the array, `i` would *not* line up with the element you just added.  `i` would be one (or more) indexes too big!

Instead of doing `camList[i].id`, try to do this:

```
camList[camList.length - 1].id
```

Comment: Well, this should be working as you said. I want to create an Array that contains only objects where it was possible to open the capture (capture.isOpend()). I'm passing the current loop variable to my object, but the object itself has a different index in the array where it was created.

Comment: @Fidel90: Then don't use `.push()`, that adds to the *end* of the array, whatever that index happens to be.  I think you want to set the index manually.  Try:  `camList[i] = camObj`.

Comment: But thats the exact reason why I use push. I know it's not easy to understand my intention here :)

Comment: By the way: camList[camList.length - 1].id works, have to look over my code again :) Thanks for the moment!

Comment: Glad I could help out :-D

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `camList` is an empty array before the start of your loop:

```
var camList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var camObj = new Camera(i);
    camList.push(camObj);
    console.log(camObj.id);
    console.log(camList[i].id);
}
```

Comment: @funkwurm: When the question was first posted, that line wasn't in it.